# setting configurable: false is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to explicitly set `configurable: false` for a property of my object and expecting that this should not allow to delete that property from my object but some how it doesn't seems working as my property is still getting deleted. What is wrong here?

**What am I doing**

```
var emp = {
    name: 'Rojer',
}

Object.defineProperty(emp, 'id', {
    configurable : false,
    value : 5100
});

delete emp.id;

for (p in emp) {
    document.write('<br/>' + emp[p]);
}
```

**The result**

Now it is only printing value for `name` property.

**I am expecting**

While it should print both `id` and `name` by ignoring `delete emp.id;` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the `configurable` property: the problem is that you need to set `enumerable` to true:

```
Object.defineProperty(emp, 'id', {
    configurable : false,
    enumerable : true,
    value : 5100
});
```

`enumerable` defaults to false, meaning the new variable (`id`) won't show up in a for/in loop, which is why you aren't seeing it.

Comment: Hi @Ethan Brown thanks, this is working for me now. Books say by default it is true for all properties defined directly on an object which entirely blocked me think on this angle. So it seems it is true for directly defined but false for properties defined using Object.defineProperty().

Comment: That is correct, Kalher: if you define it using `Object.defineProperty`, it defaults to false.